# Chrome only works on the first session for multi-session logins

Tags: google-chrome, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I haven't found anything looking like a good answer to my problem, so I'll articulate my own question:

On a Terminal-/Remote Desktop Server (2012 R2), we have a problem running Chrome where there are multiple sessions for the same user. (e.g. a shared "Front Desk" AD user where 2 or 3 people at work may be logged into 4 or 5 RDP sessions with the same user account)

The first launch of Chrome works fine for whichever session opens it. None of the other sessions can use Chrome, however, at least not until the initially launched program instance is closed.

I found an explanation followed by a very unsexy suggestion in the Chromium forums (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160676), so I'm trying to ask here instead in hope that there is a better and more intuitive solution to the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: I stumbled on this question having the same problem on one of our servers.  It looks like as recently as a couple weeks ago some updates have occurred on the linked Issue.  Did you ever find a workaround that worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround details for this issue are here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=160676

Comment: It's helpful to post some context and key details in the answer, as well as providing the link.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved by, for each concurrent session needed:

1. In chrome click on `Manage people`, then `Add person`, checking **`Create a desktop shortcut for this user`**.

[image]

2. Chrome will create a desktop shortcut with the `Target` property such as:

   `"C:\......\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"`
3. Edit the **`Target`** property of the created desktop shortcut and add a unique folder value for the `--user-data` parameter:

   `"C:\......\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1" --user-data-dir="C:\temp\user1"`

Comment: --user-data-dir   worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your log or any other trace clue.
One of my guess chrome's user data directory was locked by the chrome opened.

You might try open the chrome from cmd with this command:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:\temp\user1"
```

It is starting chrome with a new user data directory.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to uncheck the option that lets Chrome run in the background even if "closed"
Click on the Chrome menu (or press Alt+E) Select Settings Click on the link titled ‘Show advanced settings‘ Under the section headed ‘System‘ untick the box next to “Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed”